# Simple dot product

Tags: linear-algebra

I think this is simple, but i can't get my head around it.

> Given the lengths of two vectors, and the angle between them.
> $$||u||=4,\quad ||v||=3, \quad\theta=\pi/4$$
> calculate $(u-2v)\cdot(3u+v)$ and verify that the answer is $30(1-\sqrt{2})$.

My work:
$$(4-2\cdot 3)\cdot(3\cdot 4+3)\Rightarrow (-2)\cdot(15)\\
|-2|\cdot|15|\cdot\cos(\pi/4)\Rightarrow 30\cdot\sqrt2/2=15\sqrt2$$

Comment: Do you mean $||u||=4$ and $||v||=3$?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.

Comment: So if you're given only the lengths of the vectors, you have to have a different approach. The fundamental error here is that
$$
(\vec{u}-2\vec{v}) \cdot (3\vec{y}+\vec{v})
\neq 
(||\vec{u}||-2||\vec{v}||) \cdot (3||\vec{y}||+||\vec{v}||)
$$
and likewise, the length of a vector is not a linear operator;
$$
||\vec{a} + \vec{b}|| \neq ||\vec{a}|| + ||\vec{b}||
$$
I recommend that you take a hard look at the expression
$$
(\vec{u}-2\vec{v}) \cdot (3\vec{u} + \vec{v})
$$
And try to modify it to a form that you actually **can** compute.

Comment: Do you mean $(u-2v) \cdot (3u+v)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of dot product with $a,b \in \mathbb R$ we have

- $au\cdot bu= ab|u|^2$
- $av\cdot bv= ab|v|^2$
- $au\cdot bv=ab|u||v|\cos \theta$

and by distributive property for dot product we obtain

$$(u-2v) \cdot (3u+v)=u \cdot 3u+u \cdot v-2v  \cdot 3u-2v  \cdot v=$$

$$=3|u|^2+u\cdot v-6v\cdot u-2|v|^2=3|u|^2-5u\cdot v-2|v|^2$$

$$=3|u|^2-5|u||v|\cos \frac \pi 4-2|v|^2$$

with

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help! It's now solved.

$$3u^2+uv-6uv-2v^2=3u^2-2v^2-5uv=48-18-5cos(\pi/4)=30-30\sqrt2=30(1-\sqrt2)$$

Comment: You could also add that as an edit in your question.

Comment: There is some typo in your solution. Also $u^2$ should be $|u|^2$ or $\|u\|^2$.